# saving all state value at once

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to store 3 different state value (category,subcategory,squarefeet) at once in a single state and save them together in a database.I have 3 different functions for 3 different state.Right now i made 3 axios request for 3 different funtions:

```
 this.state = {
    apiUrl: config.publicRuntimeConfig.publicRuntimeConfigValue.apiUrl, 
    categoryName:'',
    subCategoryName:'',
    squareFeet:'',

};


saveValue = (e) => {
    console.log('savecategory', e.target.innerHTML);

    this.setState({
        category: e.target.innerHTML
    }, this.makingAxiosRequest);

};

makingAxiosRequest = () => {
    axios.post( this.state.apiUrl+'/api/v1/LeadSurvey/save', {
        'categoryName':this.state.category,
    }, {})
};
savedValue = (e) => {
    // console.log('savecategory', e.target.innerHTML);

    this.setState({
        subCategory: e.target.innerHTML
    }, this.makeAxiosRequest);

};

makeAxiosRequest = () => {
    axios.post( this.state.apiUrl+'/api/v1/LeadSurvey/save', {
        'subCategoryName':this.state.subCategory,
    }, {})
};



handleChange = value => {
    this.setState({
        value: value
    })
};

savingValue = () => {
    console.log('saveValue ...', this.state);


    axios.post( this.state.apiUrl+'/api/v1/LeadSurvey/save', {
        'squareFeet':this.state.value,



    }
```

But I am not being able to pass all this value in last state and save it at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide `name` property to your input or what you are using, then call `onChange(e)` passing event property and get the **name, value** properties from event and set it to the state like following:

```js
class Thingy extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {};
  }
  
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  
  render() {
    const {title} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        name
        <input name='name' onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}/>
        age
        <input name='age' onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Thingy />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you are passing the correct state names. Try something like this

```
axios.post(this.state.apiUrl+'/api/v1/LeadSurvey/save', {'categoryName':this.state.categoryName,subCategoryName:this.state.subCategoryName,'squareFeet':this.state.squareFeet});
```

pass all the state data at once instead of 3 different calls.
If those 3 values are taken from input fields you can bind the values with the state like this.

```
onChange=(e,{name,value})=>{
  this.setState({[name]:value});
}

<input name="categoryName" onChange={this.onChange}/>
```